# Accessing struct through method

Tags: c++

I have a question. I want you to make a guess what could be the type of "data" "toBit" and "b3" here. I could not figure it out.

```
data.toBit().b3;
```

Comment: What is your question? Why should we guess? There has to be decleration of `data` telling us what type `data` is. From there we could check the `toBit()`-function-signatur. Then we would have to look at its' return type. We allready know that its' return type has a public member `b3`. All this types are somewhere in your `#include` so you should have access to this header files.

Comment: `MyData`, `Bit (MyData::*)()const`, and `unsigned int : 1`.

Comment: This isn't a homework site.  You should make an attempt on the question at the very least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` has a class type.
`toBit` is a member function of that class, and returns an object of a type that has a member, `b3`.

It would be something along these lines:

```
struct Something
{
    some_type b3;
};

struct Data
{
    Something toBit();
};

Data data;
some_type x = data.toBit().b3;
```

It's impossible to guess anything more specific than that.

Comment: *"toBit is a member function of that class"* or a callable as `std::function<Something ()>`